# Jquery Burger Menu wont apply class correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css

If I click on the burger element, the function runs but does not apply the class required.

Could any shed some light on this as I when I read it, this looks like it should work, but I do not see the class being applied in the dom and theoretically once applied the drop-down menu should be visible.

HTML(minimized example):

```
<header>
  <div class = "navwrap">
  <h1 class = "logo">Logo </h1>
  <nav>
    <a class = "burger-nav"> </a>
    <h2> Main Nav</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/nav.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

  .burger-nav {
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    width:100%;
    background: url(../img/navicon.png) no-repeat 98% center;
    background-color: blue;
    cursor:pointer;
  }

  header .navwrap{
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
  }

  header nav ul {
    overflow:hidden;
    background: #505050;
    height: 0;
  }

  header nav ul .open {
    height: auto;
  }

  header nav ul li {
    float: none;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }

  header nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #404040;
  display: block;
  margin:0;
  }

}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".burger-nav").on("click", function() {

  alert("Clicked");

    $("header nav ul").toggleClass("open");

});

});
```

Comment: Ok, so I figured out why it was not applying the class and it was a silly mistake, however now when it does toggle the UL elements are display behind the next container.

Comment: Can you pls share a link to jsfiddle so that it's easier to debug?

Comment: jQuery script is fine and it is working. I guess <a class = "burger-nav"> </a> doesn't have any space on screen and click is not triggered.

Comment: I can do that now, ill have to provide more of the site to show the problem though.

Comment: use z-index in css to make it above other content.

Comment: @Tahir, click is triggered and class is applied but the LI elements are hidden behind the next container.

Comment: Oh I just got their, my height was not being affected correctly due to the way I was using CSS selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the css rule ,

Instead of **`header nav ul .open`** set it to  **`header nav ul.open`** (remove space between `ul` and `.space` class) , the first  search for element insude the ul that has .open class , the second the ul that has .open class , that's the difference

See below snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".burger-nav").on("click", function() {

      $("header nav ul").toggleClass("open");

  });

});
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {

  .burger-nav {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    width:40px;
    background: url(https://cdn.css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/threelines.png) no-repeat 98% center;
    background-color: blue;
    background-size: 50px;
    cursor:pointer;
  }

  header .navwrap{
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
  }

  header nav ul {
    overflow:hidden;
    background: #505050;
    height: 0 ;
  }

  header nav ul.open {
    height: auto;
  }

  header nav ul li {
    float: none;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }

  header nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #404040;
  display: block;
  margin:0;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <div class = "navwrap">
  <h3 class = "logo">Logo </h3>
  <nav>
    <a class = "burger-nav"> </a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Yes Boo, this was indeed the problem, a bit annoying that it took me half an hour to figure out but its part of the process right.